# MailChimp / Magento Connection Issue When Uploading Files to FTP

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, magento1.9.3, mailchimp

I am trying to connect my MailChimp account to my Magento multistore. I couldn't seem to connect it using the Access Key and Magento Connect so I have downloaded the TGZ files from Magento Marketplace, unzipped them and copied the folders into my Magento store root directory, following the instructions from MailChimp ([here](https://mailchimp.com/help/connect-or-disconnect-mailchimp-for-magento/)).

I am having two issues:

1. The following file will not copy over to my FTP: MailChimp Connect Files\skin\js\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\ebizmarts\mailchimp\system\config\form\field\array_dropdown.phtml

[image]

This is the only file that is returning an error. I have tried to upload it multiple times but I get the same error message every time. This is the only error information that's coming up on the FTP.

2. This is the main issue: MailChimp does not appear in my Magento Configuration Settings panel and therefore doesn't look like it's connected.

I have followed all the instructions to the letter (famous last words), so I'm really confused as to why it's not connecting.

Can anyone advise?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks
Anna

Answer (score 0):

Can you try copying that file to your desktop, then try uploading manually into the remote directory it's trying to create? It might be because the filepath is too long for Windows to read.

Failing that, it's likely to be file/folder permissions on the server

Comment: Thanks! I copied and pasted the array_dropdown.phtml file to my desktop and successfully dropped it in to the right folder on the FTP. Thanks Ryan. You are a genius!

Comment: The  main issue of MailChimp not appearing in my Magento Configuration Settings panel, so it doesn't look like it's connected.

Comment: @user69135 if any of the files are missing then that will happen - I'd suggest copying all files from a shorter filepath (e.g. move the mailchimp folder to desktop then re-upload)

Comment: Yes, I have tried reuploading everything from my desktop (to shorten the path) but it's still not connecting. How odd. All of the files are definately there now. The cach has been flushed before and after the upload. I have signed out of Magento and logged back in. It must be something blindingly simple that I'm not doing!

Comment: @user69135 It'll be in system -> configuration then a tab on the left column if working. Typically, extensions won't display if uploaded by a different user to that of the web server with Magento configurations, as the web server can't read the files, therefore Magento can't either (but using the connect manager creates files as web user, so it can read). Do you have shell access to the server?

Comment: Thanks, Ricky, but I'm not sure I understand your last comment. I have uploaded the MC files to the Magento root file via FTP, so surely that means these new files are on the same server as the rest of my Magento files. And yet, the system clearly isn't reading the new files and making the connection. I really cannot understand what I'm doing wrong.  Am I misunderstanding what you are saying about the server?

Comment: @user69135 yeah, the server will have file ownership, e.g. owned by the server (www-data for example) if you uploaded via ftp, the files will be owned by your user ftp account, which depending on configuration will not allow magento to read the files, for security reasons. When you install via magento connect, the server technically uploads these files into storage, so can read its own files. Your hosting company should be able to assist, you basically need all files to be owned by the web server user.

Comment: Thanks so much. I will contact the hosting company as a next step. Finger crossed that resolves things.

Comment: You were right! While the FTP uploads should have the right permission in our server set up, some of them were incorect. This has been rectified, but still no MC showing in Magento. I have raised a ticket with eBizmarts as I've tried everything else on their forum. :)